# How can I change theme?

Tags: drush

I tried `drush disable theme-name` and afterwards `drush enable theme-name`, but it didn't work.

How do you change theme with Drush?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Commands to be used in theme using drush :

```
theme-enable        => pm-enable
theme-disable       => pm-disable
theme-info          => pm-info
theme-list          => pm-list --type=theme
theme-list-enabled  => pm-list --type=theme --status=enabled
theme-set-default   => vset theme_default
theme-set-admin     => vset admin_theme
theme-status        => status theme
```

Comment: This only applies to Drupal 6 and 7.

Comment: I didn't find this worked, I had to then also do this: `drush vset theme_default THEMENAME` and because I had errors relating to my theme not being active, I couldn't access the set default through the admin pages (article I read here: http://pixelthis.gr/blog/drush-enable-theme-and-set-default)

Answer (score 36):

For ***Drush 9.5.2*** and ***Drupal 8.6.5*** I use the following:

```
drush theme:uninstall THEME_MACHINE_NAME
drush theme:enable THEME_MACHINE_NAME
drush config-set system.theme default THEME_MACHINE_NAME
```

Comment: Best answer. And if you want to set the admin theme, you can replace "default" with "admin" in the third line.

Comment: I can also confirm that these commands work with Drush 10.x and Drupal 9.x.

Comment: To set admin theme one can use: `drush config-set system.theme admin THEME_MACHINE_NAME `

Answer (score 1):

With Drush 7 and 8, it is no longer necessary to be so verbose. If you want to enable a theme use the alias:

```
drush en your-theme-name
drush dis your-theme-name
```

For example:

```
drush en seven
drush dis bartik
```

You may want to clear your caches after enabling or disabling themes. For more information please see: [DrushCommands.com](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/pm/pm-enable/)

Comment: For a theme, it is usually not enough to just enable it. You also have to set it as a default. In Drupal 8, the command is this: `drush config-set system.theme default NAME_OF_YOUR_THEME`

Comment: The question is how to change the theme. If there is already a default, you can't change it until you can set another one as default, and this does not answer that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the admin theme using Drush, you can use below command.

```
drush config-set system.theme admin <theme_machine_name>
```

Eg.

```
drush config-set system.theme admin seven
```

If the theme is not installed, first install the theme using below command

```
drush theme:en seven
```

Again run the above command to set admin theme.

Comment: This works with drupal 10.  Also useful:  drush config-get system.theme, drush config-set system.theme default olivero

Answer (score -1):

`drush dis` and `drush disable` aren't anymore valid, in Drupal 8. Their Drupal 8 equivalent are the following commands.

```
drush pm-uninstall THEME_MACHINE_NAME
drush pm-uninstall MODULE_MACHINE_NAME
```

Comment: This won't work on a theme set as default.