# How to access the administration panel if you cannot login again?

Tags: 7

I have created a custom theme. I have added the region user account menu in footer, but I forgot to add the region primary admin access.

Unfortunately I clicked on the logout button, and I am not able to log in again. The page at `/user/login` appears empty. Now how can I access the administration page?

Comment: Use Drush, see https://www.drupal.org/node/837058

Comment: You should be able to switch the theme with drush (or failing that directly in the database), the answer on this question [How do you change theme with Drush?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/178852/105) may help

Answer (score 1):

You change your default theme in setting.php.Uncomment this line in your setting.php file

```
 $conf['theme_default'] = 'garland';
```

[image]